# Error while using apt-get

Tags: apt, dpkg, rsync

I am not very expert in linux. I am just using Ubuntu for few months. Recently, I am facing the same error whenever I am trying to perform any task(mainly apt-get tasks). For example here I am trying to install htop for my purpose and this is the error that I am getting. It seems that the error is occurring due to rsync but not sure about the error nor how I can get rid of it.

```
sudo apt-get install htop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
htop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up rsync (3.1.1-3ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service vpnagentd_init at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package rsync (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsync
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and I am getting the following error

```
Setting up rsync (3.1.1-3ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and rc.local if started
insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service vpnagentd_init at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package rsync (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsync
```

It would be really helpful if someone could point out what should I do to remove this error. I am using Ubuntu 15.04. Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried this command: `dpkg-reconfigure -a`?

Comment: no I haven't..let me try

Comment: so when I do it 
dpkg-reconfigure -rsync it says 
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: rsync is broken or not fully installed

Comment: if I run without -a then it says please specify a package to reconfigure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove rsync, attempt to resolve the problem related to the vpnagentd_init script and reinstall rsync.

1) Remove rsync using `sudo apt-get remove rsync`

2) Edit /etc/init.d/vpnagentd_init and insert the following LSB tags.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vpnagentd_init
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Cisco vpn agent daemon at boot time
# Description: Cisco vpn agent daemon (believe installed by company ssl client)
### END INIT INFO
```

Source: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=53192#p575807

3) Install rsync using `sudo apt-get install rsync`

If all goes well then you shouldn't see any of those vpnagentd_init warnings and the rsync post-installation script should execute without fault.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I already removed the `rsync` and so the errors are gone actually. I will do the rest as you have suggested and see how turns up. Thanks again.